# Show or hide a series of rows with the same defined name as the title of the shape, by clicking on the shape

Tags: excel, vba, title, shapes

I am trying to replicate a subroutine from another workbook. The subroutine in the original workbook works.

The syntax are identical for both subroutines.

```vb
Sub FigurMedTittel_Klikk()

    Dim Tittel As String
    
    Tittel = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Title
    
    Select Case Tittel
    Case "BME"
        Range(Tittel).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("BMA").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("Kompleks").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "BMA"
        Range(Tittel).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("BME").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("Kompleks").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Kompleks"
        Range(Tittel).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("BMA").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select

End Sub
```

The point of the sub is to either show or hide a series of rows with the same defined name as the title of the shape, by clicking on the shape.
The problem seems to be that I need to give the shape (a rectangle) a title.

When I try to run the code I get

> "Run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)'"

Comment: Do you really need the title, or are you looking for the text in the shape (or maybe its name) ?

Comment: The Run-time error means that it is a Type mismatch. But without knowing exact line that is all we can tell, so, please create breakpoint on first statement in your method, then step-forward line by line to find exact line of crash (and tell us in an edit).

Comment: Thanks for the respons :). I tried to replicate the existing subroutine, and to do that I needed the title. However after doing some research, I am unsure whether it is possible to give shapes titles anymore. In previous versions of Excel you could give shapes a title thorugh alternative text, but that option seems to no longer be possible for the newer versions of excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not having much luck reading the `.Title` property - you could use the text in the shape or its `AlternativeText` (set via Excel Drawing Tools > Format > Alt Text)

```vb
Sub FigurMedTittel_Klikk()

    Dim shp As Shape, txt
    
    txt = Application.Caller
    
    'or  one of these other methods...
    'Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    'txt = shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text 
    'txt = shp.AlternativeText
    
    For Each r In Array("BME.", "BMA.", "Kompleks.")
        Range(Replace(r, ".", "")).EntireRow.Hidden = (txt <> r)
    Next r
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to modify it a bit, and now it works. I think the problem was that it is no longer possible to give shapes a title. New subroutine:

```
Sub FigurMedTittel_Klikk()

Dim Tittel As String
Dim RowTittel As String
Tittel = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
RowTittel = Replace(Tittel, ".", "") 

Select Case Tittel
Case "BME." 
    Range(RowTittel).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("BMA").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("Kompleks").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Case "BMA."
    Range(RowTittel).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("BME").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("Kompleks").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Case "Kompleks."
    Range(RowTittel).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("BMA").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Select
```

End Sub

Comment: Good to see you got it working.  Updated my post based on your fix.